# Port IE Bookmarks to Chrome

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file, google-chrome

I want to be able to automate the transfer of existing Internet Explorer bookmarks to Google Chrome.

We're rolling out Chrome to several users, but we want them to have their old bookmarks from IE automatically.

How should I go about this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't it just automatically offer the option to do this on install?

Comment: I believe that when Chrome is installed it asks the user if they want to do this.  Some of our users are not computer-literate enough to complete this on their own.  Thus, we wish to automate this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome has group policies for deployment.

I just started rolling it out in our org and there is a setting in their group policy templates to have it automatically import favorites without user intervention.  It also lets you set whether or not it should become the default browser, automatically install extensions, and set a whole host of other settings.

It works quite well in an active directory setting. If you don't have AD you could figure out the actual registry settings those apply and apply them some other way.

http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

Comment: Chrome has come a long way.  MSI file for deployment.  GPOs.  Even a legacy browser plugin that switches you back to IE for those few sites that need it.  I am quite happy with how our deployment is going.  Even have it autoinstalling adblock.

Comment: Very exciting stuff.  This is pretty much a dream come true for a web developer like myself.